# Motion of electron in magnetic field along two directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetohydrodynamics

I was trying to calculate the electron cyclotron frequency under earth magnetic field which has a horizontal and a vertical component.

Now when I consider the initial motion of the electron in all three directions and magnetic field along two-direction (x and y) I get 3 equations:-

$m\frac{dv_x}{dt} = -v_zB_y$

$m\frac{dv_y}{dt}=v_zB_x$

$m\frac{dv_z}{dt}=v_xB_y-v_yB_x$

Now when I try to solve these three equations by taking the time derivative of one and then putting other equations in it, it becomes very difficult to solve, Is there a mistake am I doing, or is there some alternative way to calculate the electron cyclotron frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@rob has already sketched a simple and intuitive answer.

Here is an alternative answer.
It only needs standard math techniques, and does not rely on intuition.
Since this is a homework-like question, I give only a rough sketch,
and leave the details to you.
The used [Method of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors](https://www.math24.net/method-eigenvalues-eigenvectors/) is explained
in every introductory textbook and on many web-sites.

You can rewrite your differential equations in matrix form.
$$m\begin{pmatrix} \dot{v}_x \\ \dot{v}_y \\ \dot{v}_z \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -B_y \\ 0 & 0 & B_x \\ B_y & -B_x & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{pmatrix}. \tag{1}$$

It begins by trying an exponential approach
$$\begin{pmatrix}v_x(t)\\v_y(t)\\v_z(t)\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{pmatrix}e^{\lambda t}. \tag{2}$$
where $A_x$, $A_y$, $A_z$ and $\lambda$ are constants which are still unknown.

Plugging approach (2) into equation (1) gives:
$$\lambda m\begin{pmatrix} A_x \\ A_y \\ A_z \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -B_y \\ 0 & 0 & B_x \\ B_y & -B_x & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A_x \\ A_y \\ A_z \end{pmatrix} \tag{3}$$

This equation (3) has non-zero solutions $\vec{A}$ only for certain values of $\lambda$
(the so-called eigenvalues). These eigenvalues turn out to be:
$$\lambda_1 = 0,\ \lambda_2=+i\frac{B}{m},\ \lambda_3=-i\frac{B}{m}$$
where $B=\sqrt{B_x^2+B_y^2}$.

From $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ you have already found the cyclotron frequency $\omega=\frac{B}{m}$.

For all three eigenvalues ($\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$)
you can find the corresponding eigenvectors ($\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,\vec{A}_3$).

Then the most general solution is a linear combination of all three:
$$\vec{v}(t)=c_1 \vec{A}_1e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2\vec{A}_2e^{\lambda_2t}+c_3\vec{A}_3 e^{\lambda_3t}$$

Doing the math you will find
$$\begin{pmatrix}v_x(t)\\v_y(t)\\v_z(t)\end{pmatrix}
=c_1\begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y\\0\end{pmatrix}
+c_2\begin{pmatrix}B_y\\-B_x\\+iB\end{pmatrix}e^{+i\omega t}
+c_3\begin{pmatrix}B_y\\-B_x\\-iB\end{pmatrix}e^{-i\omega t}.$$

Of course, at the end $\vec{v}$ needs to be real, not complex.
This will give some constraints on the constants ($c_1, c_2, c_3$),
and you can rewrite $e^{\pm i\omega t}$
in terms of $\cos(\omega t)$ and $\sin(\omega t)$.

Comment: Nice answer. To connect the two approaches, note that *every* antisymmetric matrix representing the cross product (even one with all of $B_{x,y,z} \neq 0$) has one zero eigenvalue and two imaginary eigenvalues which are complex conjugates. The magnitude of the imaginary eigenvalues is the cyclotron frequency, and depends on the magnitude of the magnetic field. Your eigenvector $\vec A_1$ points in the direction of $\vec B$; if $c_1\neq0$, the particle's motion is helical rather than circular. Diagonalizing the matrix is closely related to rotating into a $\vec B$-centered coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

At my location, Earth's magnetic field is mostly vertical,  but the horizontal component doesn't point due north, either. So really you have even more components in any rectilinear coordinate system.

If all you want is the cyclotron frequency, neglect gravity and neglect true North and choose your favorite axis parallel to the magnetic field.  Then you have only one cyclotron frequency, which depends on the magnetic field magnitude.

Comment: can we take the average of both magnetic field and then calculate cyclotron frequency?

Comment: The magnetic field is a vector, obeying the superposition principle: it has one magnitude and one direction at any point in space, no matter how many sources contribute to it. You cannot make two magnetic fields by choosing a clumsy coordinate system, so there is no "both" to take the average of.

Comment: okk I got it now.